# Trying to read a text file in res/raw with scanner

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner, android-resources

Hello,

I am trying to read a file with a [`Scanner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html) so I can use the input of the strings to construct other objects. However my scanner is always throwing a `NullPointerException` when trying to create it. I have a `pig.txt` text file in the `res/raw` folder but my scanner can not seem to access it. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have comment out other code of the method but still get an exception.

```
public void loadAchievements() {
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pig));

        /**
         * s = s.useDelimiter("."); Scanner StringScanner; StringScanner =
         * new Scanner(s.next()); StringScanner =
         * StringScanner.useDelimiter(":"); String keep =
         * StringScanner.next(); String StringKeeper = StringScanner.next();
         * this.achievementBoard.add(new Achievement_Item(keep,
         * StringKeeper)); StringScanner.close(); s.close();
         **/
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("NULLPOINTER");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the stream *isn't* actually `null`?

Comment: It's [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). You can use [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) to debug, don't use `System.out`.

Answer (score 1):

```
I had this problem today, and I resolved somehow.
I know that old question, but I would share it if others have stuck.





 public class Question {

        private int numberOfQuestion;
        private String[] myquestion;

        public Question(InputStream file_name) {
            Scanner scanner = null;

            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(file_name);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Question", "Scanner :" + e);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            this.numberOfQuestion = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            myquestion = new String[numberOfQuestion];

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestion; ++i) {
                myquestion[i] = scanner.nextLine();

            }

            scanner.close();


        }
    ---------------------------------------------------------
call:

try { 
  MyScanner myScanner = new MyScanner(getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.input_question)); 
   } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.d("Error", "input_question.txt"); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

openRawResource() method can **only** be used to open **drawable, sound, and raw resources**; it will fail on string and color resources. Since your pig.txt is a text file that contains a String, openRawResource() won't be able to open a new stream therefore your stream is null.

Comment: then what can I use to to open up a string file?